# Bitwise AND or similar operation on data-frame rows in R?

Tags: r, vector, bit-manipulation, dataframe, operation

I have two data frames `A` and `B`, both of the same dimensions. The row and column labels are not guaranteed to be identically ordered between frames.

Both frames contain values `0` and `1`, with `1` indicating that a directed "edge" exists between a row and column of the frame (and, accordingly, `0` indicating no connection).

I would like to find "edges" common to both frames. In other words, I want a data frame of the same dimensions as `A` and `B`, which contain `1` values where there is a `1` at a row and column of both `A` and `B`.

Presently, I am looping through rows and columns and testing if both are `1`.

This works, but I imagine there is a more efficient way of doing this. Is there a way to do the equivalent of a "bitwise AND" operation on row vectors of data frames, which returns a row vector I can stuff back into a new data frame? Or is there another more intelligent (and efficient) approach?

**EDIT**

Matrix multiplication is quite faster than my initial approach. Sorting was the key to making this work.

```
findCommonEdges <- function(edgesList) {
    edgesCount <- length(edgesList)
    print("finding common edges...")
    for (edgesIdx in 1:edgesCount) {
        print(paste("...searching against frame", edgesIdx, sep=" "))
        edges <- edgesList[[edgesIdx]]
        if (edgesIdx == 1) {
            # define commonEdges data frame as copy of first frame
            commonEdges <- edges
            next
        }
        #
        # we reorder edge data frame row and column labels 
        # to do matrix multiplication and find common edges
        #
        edges <- edges[order(rownames(commonEdges)), order(colnames(commonEdges))]
        commonEdges <- commonEdges * edges
    }
    commonEdges
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use normal multiplication for that! :-)

```
// generate data
a = matrix(rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), nrow = 10)
b = matrix(rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), nrow = 10)

a * b // this is the result!
```

You could also use logical & operator, which is the "bitwise and" you are looking for. Your expression would then look like `(a & b) + 0` 
(the `+ 0` will just convert from boolean back to integer).

Note: with dataframes it works exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks, @joran :-) This example shows R is very elegant language, and I love to enjoy its elegancy :-)

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense, I just need to order the two frames in the same way, so that the result is correct.

Comment: note that you should not confuse `&` with the "bitwise and" operator `&` as in C. You can get that from the `bitops` package with the function `bitAnd()`.

Comment: @Sacha, yeah, we should say "elementwise" instead of "bitwise" to be correct, but I think we understood each other with OP...

Comment: Yeah this was more meant at random people googling "Bitwise and in R" or something and not reading the entire post:)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1,25,replace = TRUE),5,5))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1,25,replace = TRUE),5,5))
df3 <- matrix(0,5,5)
df3[df1 == 1 & df2 == 1] <- 1
> df3
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

I've ended up with a matrix, but you can convert it back to a data frame again, if need be. But if you're just dealing with 0/1 data, there's no real reason not to use matrices. (Then again, I don't know many details about your specific situation...)